# Gluon Scene Builder won't launch

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I have recently installed Scene Builder, specifically the .jar. I am trying to launch it without any success. My OS is OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4. My Java version is 8, Update 92.

Firstly, I have opted for double clicking at the .jar file (the Jar Launcher version is 15.0.1) which prints out this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMaBj.png).

Looking into console, I have found this report:

```
28/04/16 12:11:14,468 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: 
(com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.291552[4267]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

Executing the following command in Terminal

```
java -jar SceneBuilder-8.1.1.jar
```

prints out the following message

```
Exception in Application start method
Apr 28, 2016 11:18:40 AM     com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$SceneBuilderUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: An exception was thrown:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.font.MacFontFinder.populateFontFileNameMap(MacFontFinder.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(PrismFontFactory.java:1740)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:469)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:194)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getDefaultAAMode(LogicalFont.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getStrike(LogicalFont.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFont.getStrike(PrismFont.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.setContent(PrismTextLayout.java:138)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getTextLayout(Text.java:229)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:184)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$5.invalidated(Text.java:501)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:82)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.setFont(Text.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText.<init>(LabeledText.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.<init>(LabeledSkinBase.java:125)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.<init>(LabelSkin.java:39)
    at javafx.scene.control.Label.createDefaultSkin(Label.java:158)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:875)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2392)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Apr 28, 2016 11:18:40 AM com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$SceneBuilderUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: An exception was thrown:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.font.MacFontFinder.populateFontFileNameMap(MacFontFinder.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(PrismFontFactory.java:1740)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:469)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:194)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getDefaultAAMode(LogicalFont.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getStrike(LogicalFont.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFont.getStrike(PrismFont.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.setContent(PrismTextLayout.java:138)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getTextLayout(Text.java:229)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:184)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$5.invalidated(Text.java:501)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:82)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.setFont(Text.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText.<init>(LabeledText.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.<init>(LabeledSkinBase.java:125)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.<init>(LabelSkin.java:39)
    at javafx.scene.control.Label.createDefaultSkin(Label.java:158)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9049)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2392)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.font.MacFontFinder.populateFontFileNameMap(MacFontFinder.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(PrismFontFactory.java:1740)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:469)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:194)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getDefaultAAMode(LogicalFont.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getStrike(LogicalFont.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFont.getStrike(PrismFont.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.setContent(PrismTextLayout.java:138)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getTextLayout(Text.java:229)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:184)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$5.invalidated(Text.java:501)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.bind(ObjectPropertyBase.java:174)
    at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.bind(StyleableObjectProperty.java:75)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText.<init>(LabeledText.java:82)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.<init>(LabeledSkinBase.java:125)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.<init>(LabelSkin.java:39)
    at javafx.scene.control.Label.createDefaultSkin(Label.java:158)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:875)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:875)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:875)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1643)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1720)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:846)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.openWindow(AbstractWindowController.java:148)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.openWindow(DocumentWindowController.java:1097)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:394)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartMac(AppPlatform.java:207)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:99)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:353)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp
```

Comment: Have you tried to run Scene Builder from DMG package? Is it throw such exception?

Comment: With your same settings (Mac and Java version), the `SceneBuilder-8.1.1.jar` works for me, both double clicking on it or from command line. Your problem may be related to this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089900)

Comment: Right, it truly was related to the bug. I opened the Font Book app, went to File > "Restore Standard Fonts" and now it works fine! Thank you, José!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie in MacFontFinder, hence I opened Font Book and went to File > Restore Standard Fonts. Now launching the Scene Builder proceeds without any issues.